# Kivy Language VS Python 3 Generated GUI w/ Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

With Python and Kivy I am finding there are two ways I can create the GUI for my application. The way I generally am seeing to do it in the examples/documentation is via the "Kivy Language" making a .kv file and filling it with JSON style markup in order to dictate to GUI's layout, style, and behavior.

I have more experience with Python than things like XML and JSON specifically so I found it more comfortable to make functions/classes to programmatically make/add elements to layouts.

Is there any convention I am violating by going about it this way? Are there notable benefits to using .kv files rather than having it all in pure python?

Comment: I would say kv is just easier to look at and grasp what is going on. Just think about a case of nested BoxLayouts, so much easier if you are using kv files. But sometimes error messages are more useful when using pure python. In kv you can do a lot without generating any error.

Comment: Ultimately it sounds like a "Personal Preference" thing. I'll be more diligent in exploring .kv while building in Python. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Yes it is. I would highly recommend testing kv and using it at least a little bit. I feel it makes it a lot easier

Comment: From my experience I find kivy language easier and faster to write. However i have faced a few situations where using pure python allowed me to manipulate things which i couldn't by using a kv file. For example when I needed to dynamically change labels which were bound to variables outside the the class's `self` or `root` scope.